# looking for idiomatic way to join string representations of objects

Tags: c++, boost, idioms

Considering we have this:

sample code A:

```
struct parameter
{
    string name, value;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const parameter& p)
{
    return out << p.name << "=" << p.value;
}
```

sample code B:

```
auto seq = {
   parameter{ "language", "En" },
   parameter{ "q", "search+term" }
};

vector<string> tmp;
transform(begin(seq), end(seq), std::back_inserter(tmp),
    [](const auto& p) {
        ostringstream out;
        out << p;
        return out.str();
    });
auto result = boost::algorithm::join(tmp, "&");
```

Is there any way to make *sample code B* more idiomatic? I am trying to avoid the use of `tmp`, when computing `result`.

Initially I tried to call `boost::algorithm::join` directly on `seq` (that doesn't work, because join only works on sequences of characters as joinable elements).

I could also use a single `ostringstream` and forego `boost::algorithm::join` completely (but that would append an extra `&`), or iterate on number of elements, and avoiding appending an extra ampersand at the end explicitly, or define my own ostream iterator (but that [is a lot of code to write](https://github.com/jonstewart/liblightgrep/blob/master/include/ostream_join_iterator.h)).

Thanks

Comment: You miss an argument to transform. Is it supposed to be insert_iterator for tmp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something more idiomatic, you could use [`boost::adaptors::transformed`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html) in the following way:

```
std::vector<parameter> seq = {{"language", "En"}, {"q", "search+term"}};
auto result = boost::algorithm::join(seq | 
   boost::adaptors::transformed([](parameter const &p){return p.name + "=" + p.value;}), 
   "&");
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17c31f34dd337517)

No temporary vector, no expensive string-streams.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, and missing argument to std::transform is `insert_iterator` to tmp, the easiest way to do this (and fastest!) is something like following:

```
std::ostringstream out;
for (auto&& item : seq)
     out << item << "&";
std::string str = out.str();
if (str.size() > 0)
   str.resize(str.size() - 1);
```

There is no need to use convoluted transform with ugly lambda syntax, and there is not need to create a temporary vector only to call join on it, and allocate all over again.